Suddenly received "Error: Source file not found" while coding java in VS Code. Any tips on a solution?
As I was coding through some exercises for my intro to java course, I suddenly started receiving this error on all my java files, even the ones that were just executing perfectly. I am on a Macbook Pro M3 running JDK-21 and the Java extension pack in VS Code. Here is an example of the error I am receiving in terminal:

Kelley@MacBook-Pro-2 Java-Programmering-24 %  /usr/bin/env /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/j
dk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --enable-preview --source 21 -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionM
essages -cp /Users/Kelley/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/e368816d4e58
bb1f0f006da99c9bb049/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Java-Programmering-24_f689343/bin HelloWorld
error: source file not found: HelloWorld
Kelley@MacBook-Pro-2 Java-Programmering-24 %

I have made sure to set my Java Home and confirmed it in the terminal, I have also set my settings.json to the following:
{
  "jdk.jdkhome": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home",
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
  "jdk.runConfig.vmOptions": "--enable-preview --source 21",
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "always",
  "[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
  },
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-21",
      "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}


Try to write full path to jdk

The error source file not found: HelloWorld usually indicates that the compiler cannot find the specified source file. Check your file location or classpath.
